# Error de syntaxis al usar parametros Delphi FireDAC + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

Estoy con un problema que no logro descifrar. La situacion es la siguiente:
Tengo un procedimiento al cual llamo pasandole un string, que basicamente es el nombre de una tabla.
En este caso particular es "sys_configuracion".

Ese procedimiento basicamente ejecuta las siguiente lineas:

```
Query.Close();
Query.ParamByName('TABLA').AsString := Tabla;
Query.Open;
```

"Query" basicamente tiene esto:

```
SELECT * FROM :TABLA;
```

Por ende deberia ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_configuracion;
```

Verdad?

Pues, aparentemente estoy teniendo un error. Ya que al probarlo y ejecutar mi procedimiento sucede esto:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near ":TABLA:" syntax error.
```

**¿SQLite funciona distinto con los parametros?**
No encuentro por que falla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en cualquier sitio de la sentencia SQL no se pueden usar parámetros. Por ejemplo, no puedes defiir una SQL como esta:

```
:PARAM1 * FROM tabla1
```

Y definir el parámetro como `'SELECT'`. Aunque la sentencia sea correcta, te devolverá error.

Lo mismo pasa con el que estás definiendo tú. Al menos en otros motores es así e imagino que igual pasa en SQLite.
En este caso, creo que sólo te queda definir la consulta concatenando cadenas y sin utilizar ese parámetro.

```
Query.Close();
Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + Tabla;
// Query.ParamByName('TABLA').AsString := Tabla;
Query.Open;
```